# why cannot directly get assosiation table( embeddable bean ) infomation withou entity information hibernate hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a association ,simple as this :
 friendship association between peoples;

```
@JoinTable(name = "friendship", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "people1_id"))

@MapKeyManyToMany(targetEntity = People.class, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "people2_id"))
@Column(name = "a_value")
public Map<People, Friendship> getFriendship() {
    return friendshipInfos;
}

@embeddable
class Friendship {
 Long years ;
}
```

table :

```
friendship {
  people1_id bigint(20) NOT NULL;
  people2_id bigint(20) NOT NULL;
  years  tinyint(3) NOT NULL;

}
```

how can i directly search friendship infomation using hql and i donot require people infomation ;
using sql i know:

```
select count(*) from friendship fs where  fs.year >2 ;
```

but how hql do to get the embeddable bean ?
i use

```
 select fs from  Friendship fs where fs.year >2;
```

but throw exception

```
exception:org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Friendship  is not mapped
```

Comment: @Table(name="friendship ") i think you missed mapping table in your Friendship entity..

Comment: @sasi yes , Friendship is embddable , it has no mapping table ; but why can i get the embeddable bean directly

Comment: You are working against yourself. If you want to query your Friendship objects directly why structure your project to forbid it? If your business needs Friendship to be a domain object make it a domain object.